# Getting all the items from table A and how many times those items occur in Table B

Tags: php, mysql, join, count

I've been scouring for a few hours, got close, now I'm stuck.  I have a table of **moods** and  a table of **verses** containing mood IDS.  I need a MySQL query that gives me all of the (limited, permanent list of moods you can choose) and the number of times verses contained those moods. There are plenty of verses containing the unique ID's of the moods yet I'm just getting 1 record or errors from the following attempts :

```
SELECT moods.mood_text, COUNT(distinct verse.uid) AS num_moods
FROM moods INNER JOIN
     verse
     ON verse.mood = moods.uid
```

(this gets me one mood and a count, but I have 30 moods and I can see verses with way more than one mood)

```
SELECT count(verse.uid) AS verseCount, mood_text, moods.uid
FROM moods LEFT JOIN
     verse
     ON moods.uid = verse.mood
```

(returns the same thing)

I could sure use some help?  Thank you

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: verse.mood = moods.uid

Comment: ok, heading in!

Comment: DUDE!! thats insane and frustratingly simple lol.  Thank you!!!